# What is the best implementation for an application that regards open edits by users?

Tags: php, sql, design-patterns

I am currently developing a web application that users can upload movies/books information to a large database. I am trying to create a system where there are no duplicates in titles. I have a coupe of options but I do not think I am experienced enough to make the proper one:

**Options:**

1. make it so once a user uploads the book's info and pictures..then other users will be able to edit this openly.
2. upload every single possible movie myself or
3. allow users to upload multiple of the same ones.

**Problems:**

1. this problem will involve users who vandalize
2. this seems almost impossible
3. duplicate of data

Is there anyone who've encountered this problem before who can think of a better solution for this?

This application is built using PHP/MySQL.

Comment: How are you storing this metadata?

Comment: movies table with the fields: title, year, and summary

Comment: You have two questions: 1. How to handle titles so that you don't get duplicates. 2. How to allow edits without getting vandalism. Edit this question to contain only one and create a new question for #2.

Comment: Regarding books: Force the usage of ISBN which is unique and can easily be found at Amazon etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Wiki-style database, where users are free to add and edit details but you appoint moderators that can approve or disapprove of added / edited details.

Score every member that uploads good information and after they have reached a certain score, they can edit information freely without moderators checking it. Give vandals a negative score and prevent anyone with a score below a certain point to add information.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i did some thinking. There is this site I like, they use a kind of voting system or edits. On this particular site there are large lists of 'movies' and the movies are poorly documented. People can submit the names or 'actors' or 'actresses' that star in these films. After a certain number of people make the same suggestions, they are committed. The site I am referencing is pornhub.com

If you go to watch a 'film' on there, under the flash video there is an option to 'Add a Pornstar'. I was thinking you could utilize this same concept of user blind-voted edits/comments. Then you can use option 1 without problem 1.

Comment: Hrm, this idea is interesting. How will I prevent duplicates with this idea? But this is great for editing though!

Comment: You could try adding some sort of validation to their input to make sure its in a certain format so you can easily compare it with other stuff. The trick will be to find a way to make this validation not too restrictive (so the user doesn't get upset) by maybe doing some auto formatting of their input, maybe asking their approval of the post-formatted data.

Answer (score 0):

There are two general things that could help you :

- Frameworks. There are a lot of good frameworks which have multiple user input control functions. I suggest trying out Zend or CodeIgniter. Zend may be more complicated on the other hand it is a bit more flexible. CodeIgniter has a larger community and is a bit simpler, however lacks flexibility and sometimes speed.
- CMSs. What you need is not a standard  so I suggest trying out Drupal it is somtimes called a CMS/Framework so it is very flexible and it has a role and permissions system which should meet your needs, if not you can extend it.

In my personal view Drupal is the way to go, it will save you a lot of time. Good luck.

Comment: Neither of these solve the problem of duplicate content